# Which are the file formats supported in radimage editor?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

My issue:
I am using telrick image editor in my aspx web page.Now am not able to Load *.tiff/*.tif images in my editor.so i can't edit the same.

I haven't see the doc for the supported file formats by telrik radimage editor.
i have go through the Dev docs.But the are used only(jpg, bmp, png, gif).
Any one have any idea.

I need a Dev doc clearly specify the list of supported image format by telrik image editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/mvc/need-to-learn-rad-image-editor-functioning.aspx#2598899), TIFF file format is not supported, nor will it ever be supported.  The problem comes from the fact that the TIFF format is not supported by all major browsers and RadImageEditor requires that the image can be displayed in the browser.  As of now, the supported file formats by RadImageEditor are jpeg, png, bmp, and gif.